# Vagrant - windows box waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes

Tags: vagrant

I am running vagrant on Ubuntu 14.04 and have problem with running windows box http://aka.ms/vagrant-xp-ie8 .
After sudo vagrant up, i constantly see

**Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...**

I ran 'vagrant up --debug 2>log' , and it looks like 
[this](https://gist.github.com/tmkdudek/98636c7962200ce9bc68)

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.box = "http://aka.ms/vagrant-xp-ie8"
config.winrm.username = 'IEuser'
config.winrm.password = 'Passw0rd!'
config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
config.vm.network "public_network"
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   vb.gui = true
 end
```

end

Do you have idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm running Vagrant on Mac OS and getting the same results as you are. In my case the WinXP VM does come up, but Vagrant command-line times out for some reason. In my case the WinXP is usable, so maybe this is a good enough state for you? You could also try skipping Vagrant and using the VirtualBox images from http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/.

Comment: No, i could not because i need this vm to run unit tests automatically

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues when setting up Windows guest VMs. I was using the IE11/Win7 VM from http://modern.ie.

Installing the latest version of the VirtualBox guest additions resolved it for me under OSX. Under Windows, I also turned on hardware virtualization in my BIOS.

Comment: After switch to newest virtualbox and this windows image ferventcoder/win2008r2-x64-nocm it started to work fine.